# AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_name_to_fitted_passthrough'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, streamlit, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am predicting the IPL match win probability. While deploying the model using streamlit it show this error:

```
AttributeError:  'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_name_to_fitted_passthrough'
```

That's my code:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

trf = ColumnTransformer([('trf',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,drop='first'), 
['batting_team','bowling_team','city'])],remainder='passthrough')
```

pipeline code

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
('step1',trf),
('step2',LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear'))])
```

Comment: can you add some data?

Comment: This is a versioning issue: your model was trained in a different version of sklearn than you are using in streamlit.

Answer (score 3):

See the version of your sklearn in the environment while building and saving the model using

```
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

do the same in the environment where you are loading the model using the same.

probably they aren't the same.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Run your whole code/each cell again and then again run streamlit run file.py.