# AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '_name_to_fitted_passthrough' however versions of sklearn are the same

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
model_loaded = joblib.load(path + model)
print(model_loaded.__getstate__()['_sklearn_version'])
res = model_loaded.predict(binance)
```

> 1.2.1
>
> 479 for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
>
> --> 480     Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
>
> AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute
> '_name_to_fitted_passthrough'

```
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

> The scikit-learn version is 1.2.1.

Before today all was fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute '\_name\_to\_fitted\_passthrough'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75462901/attributeerror-columntransformer-object-has-no-attribute-name-to-fitted-pas)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method to check the pkl training version is not correct. I've enabeled warnings and it showed me that I was using 1.1.1 so downgrading solved the problem